# Gitlab CI allow manual action, when previous stage failed

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, and it works OK generally.
My problem is that my testing takes more than 10 minutes and it not stable (YET..) so occasionally randomly it fails on a minor test that I don't care for.

Generally, after retry, it works, but if I need an urgent deploy I need to wait another 10 minutes.
When we have an urgent bug, another 10 minutes is waaaay too much time, so I am looking for a way to force deploy even when the test failed.

I have the next pseudo ci yaml scenario that I'd failed to find a way to accomplish

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

setup_and_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build.sh

test_branch:
  stage: test
  script:
    - test.sh


deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```

I'm looking for a way to deploy manually if the test phase failed.
but if I add `when: manual` to the deploy, then deploy never happens automatically.

so a flag like `when: auto_or_manual_on_previous_fail` will be great.

currently, there is no such flag in Gitlab ci.

Do you have any idea for a workaround or a way to implement it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to skip the test in case of an emergency release.

For that, follow "[Skipping Tests in GitLab CI](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/skipping-tests-gitlab-ci/)" from  [Andi Scharfstein](https://www.cqse.eu/en/team/andi-scharfstein/), and:

- add "skip test" in the commit message triggering that emergency release
- check a variable on the test stage

That is:

```
.test-template: &test-template
  stage: tests
  except:
    variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[skip[ _-]tests?\]/i
    - $SKIP_TESTS
```

> As you can see above, we also included the variable `$SKIP_TESTS` in the except block of the template.
>   This is helpful when triggering pipelines manually from GitLab’s web interface.
>   Here’s an example:

[image: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/skipping-tests-gitlab-ci/skip_tests.png]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to control the job attribute of your deploy job by leveraging parent-child pipelines (gitlab 12.7 and above). This will let you decide if you want the job in the child pipeline to run as `manual`, or `always`

Essentially, you will need to have a .gitlab-ci.yml with:

```yml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - child-deploy
```

child-deploy stage will be used to run the child pipeline, in which the deploy job will run with the desired attribute.
Your test could generate as artifact the code for deploy section. For example, in the after_script section of your test, you can check the value of CI_JOB_STATUS builtin variable to decide if you want to write the child job to run as manual or always:

```yml
my_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "testing, exit 0 on success, exit 1 on failure"
  after_script:
    - if [ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" == "success" ]; then WHEN=always; else WHEN=manual; fi
    - |
      cat << 'EOF' > deploy.yml
      stages:
        - deploy
      my_deploy:
        stage: deploy
        rules:
          - when: $WHEN
        script:
          - echo "deploying"
       EOF 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - deploy.yml
```

Note that variable expension is disabled in the heredoc section, by the use of single quoted 'EOF'. If you need variable expension, remember to escape the $ of $WHEN.

Finally, you can trigger the child pipeline with deploy.yml

```yml
gen_deploy:
  stage: child-deploy
  when: always
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: deploy.yml
        job: my_test
    strategy: depend
```